# How do you control a hyperactive child?

Tags: pre-schooler, attention

How do you control a hyperactive child?

My niece who is a 5 year old is very hyperactive; it's unbelievable and it's hard to get her to settle and do something.  If she does a puzzle or plays a game then she ends up moving away from that and finds another distraction and won't stay with one thing for too long.

Answer (score 4):

High energy is natural. It means you're doing a good job. Your niece has proper nutrition and rest. You need to wear that kid out. Take them to the park or an indoor play area. If they are afraid or passive, get involved. Chase the child around, play tag, hide and seek. If you can, find some nature and take them for a walk outside in the dirt and wilderness. Barring that, take her for a walk around the neighborhood.